# Is there a debian/other package for hypothetical names/addresses/cities of people?

Tags: debian, dictionary

On Debian, we have a package like `wamerican` that comprises of words (`/usr/share/dict/american-english`) from an American dictionary. Are there similar Debian/other packages for people's names, addresses, cities (e.g. John Doe, or 10 Downing Street, or Cairo) etc?

Comment: It would be very simple to write a small program/script that creates a random address using a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) `ruby` gem that randomly outputs pieces of data out of a very similar data set.

The data it uses is contained in its `yml` files in the subdirectories of `lib`.